# Split string to 140 char chunks

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

This is my function:

```
char** split_string(char* message){

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int numberOfMsgs = 0;
  int charsInLastMsg = (int)(strlen(message)%140);


  if((int)strlen(message) > 140*4){
    return NULL;
  }

  if((int)(strlen(message)%140)){
    numberOfMsgs = (int)(strlen(message)/140) + 1;
  }
  else{
    numberOfMsgs = (int)(strlen(message)/140);
  }

  printf("message length = %d, we will have %d messages, and last msg will have %d characters\n", (int)strlen(message), numberOfMsgs, charsInLastMsg);


  char **m = malloc(numberOfMsgs * sizeof(char*));
  for (j =0 ; j <= numberOfMsgs; j++){
    m[j] = malloc(141 * sizeof(char));
  }

  for(i=0;i<numberOfMsgs;i++){
    if(i == numberOfMsgs - 1){

      memcpy(m[i], message + (140*i), charsInLastMsg);
      m[i][charsInLastMsg] = '\0';
    }
    else{
      memcpy(m[i], message + (140*i), 140);
      m[i][140] = '\0';

    }
    printf("m%d = %s\n", i, m[i]);
  }
  return m;
}
```

Which I'm calling like this:

```
char* message = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100.";

int i=0;
char** m = split_string(message);
while(*m){
  printf("string%d = %s\n", i, m[i]);       //Problem at this line.
  m++;
}
```

But, when I run it, I'm getting a segmentation fault at the line indicated above. If I don't print, the program runs fine, so I think the function split_string() is alright.

What am I doing wrong? I'm a newbie, plz help.

/************************************EXPECTED O/P**********************************/

I want the string to be split into 140 char strings as below:

```
string0 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
string1 = , 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71
string2 = , 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100.
```

Comment: you are going out of bounds in array `m`.. allocating `m[j] = malloc(140 * sizeof(char))` and then trying `m[i][140] = '\0';`.. `m` goes from `0` to `139`

Comment: The problem is not within the printf, it a consequence of your split_string function not working. BTW what is your expected output ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the buffer overflow. I have edited the question. Please take a look.
Btw, the printf in split_string() works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the problem working with arrays, the information about its size should be stored somewhere, you can never know looking at a `char **` how many members it has.

That is why null-terminated strings (c strings) exist, the `NULL` char marks its end, so you have to iterate through the whole string until you find NULL to know it's length.

Anyway, I´d suggest you modify your `split_string()` function to:

```
char** split_string(char* message, size_t * n_msgs) {
   //...
   *n_msgs = numberOfMsgs;
   ///
}
```

And then:

```
size_t msgs = 0;
char** m = split_string(message, &msgs);
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code. You have already fixed some.

Your client code

```
while (*m) {
    printf("string%d = %s\n", i, *m);
    i++;
    m++;
}
```

(where I have taken the liberty to replace `m[i]` with `i` always 0 with `*m`) suggests that the char-pointer array `m` is `NULL`-terminated, i.e. that a `NULL` pointer indicates the end of the string list. (Much like a `'\0'` character indicates the end of a string.)

But your function `split_string` doesn't put a `NULL` pointer at the end: Your client code will read beyond valid memory.

```
char **m = malloc(numberOfMsgs * sizeof(char*));
```

Here, you should allocate `(numberOfMsgs + 1)` strings, one extra for the `NULL`.

```
for (j =0 ; j <= numberOfMsgs; j++){
    m[j] = malloc(141 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Here, you should only allocate `numberOfMsgs` strings. The `NULL` string doesn't have to be allocated, just be set to `NULL`:

```
m[numberOfMsgs] = NULL;
```

Finally, you should free the allocated memory. In your case, you can't do that, because you have incremented (and thus changed) the base pointer `m`. The OS can't free the memory, because the new `m` isn't registered by the memory allocator.

So, for example:

```
char **m = split_string(message, 140);
int i = 0;

while (m[i]) {
    printf("%d: '%s'\n", i, m[i]);
    free(m[i]);
    i++;
}

free(m);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this answer. I'm making the suggested changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is an infinite loop. You are testing the expression `*m` which never changes, so you will keep increasing `i` and eventually `m[i]` will refer to memory that has not been allocated.

Comment: My mistake, I have edited the question. i++ was supposed to be m++.

Answer (score 1):

You should change 
`for (j =0 ; j <= numberOfMsgs; j++){
    m[j] = malloc(141 * sizeof(char));`

to

```
for (j =0 ; j < numberOfMsgs; j++){
m[j] = malloc(141 * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: I just tried it. Ran with valgrind. Got rid of some invalid reads.
But the seg fault is still there.

Comment: Try memmove instead of memcopy. memcopy has some issues with overlapping arrays. Just search for memmove

Comment: Still same problem with memmove().

Comment: No surprise there: in`this case `memcpy` is the function of choice, because you are copying from the input string to freshly allocated memory, which definitely don't overlap. (Not that it can't hurt to use `memmove`.)