# Split wchar_t on size

Tags: c++

I want split a wchar_t string on size: e.g. `wchar_t* t= L"Abcdefghijk"` and I want to split on size 4 then the chunks I should get are: `{"Abcd", "efgh", "ijk"}`

I wrote the following code for doing  this, however it has bugs:

```
    int maxSize=10;
    while ((lqs > maxSize) && (it < lqs))
    {
        wchar_t *strng = (wchar_t*)calloc(2, sizeof(wchar_t));
        int fragLen = 0;

        while ((it < lqs) && (fragLen < maxSize))
        {
            wcsncat_s(strng, (wcslen(strng) + 1) * 2, &queryShapeTemp[it], 1);
            ++it;
            ++fragLen;
        }
        
        lqs = lqs - maxSize;
        free(strng);
    }
```

Is there an efficient way of splitting strings or chunking strings based on size without using "std::wstring" or other stl libraries?

Comment: Try searching SO using `[c] split string chunks`.

Comment: Why do you not want to use STL? Please specify your constraints.

Comment: @Christian.K: I tried but most solution or atleast  the ones I could find use std::wstring or stl libraries which I do not want to use

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I want to learn without using STL therefore :)

Comment: Based on your coding style and your aversion to the C++ standard library I think you should remove c++ tags and retag as [tag:c] instead.

Comment: That's why I suggested to include the "C" (language) tag `[c]`. Also what about the very first [hit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26607074/21567) (I have not tried it, YMMV).

Comment: Looks like you're using C++ (cast the result of calloc). C and C++ are different languages: what works in one does not necessarily work in the other.

Comment: Note that on some platforms wide character strings can be multi-byte and the split might therefore not be on a character boundary.

Comment: there's nothing C++ in your code. STL is an important part of C++ which is what makes many things easier to write and easier to optimize in C++

Comment: The question should be tagged according to which language you would like to use.  NOT according to the code style. Please ignore comments recommending to use C language tag for code that you are building with a C++ compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version with a single allocation:

```
#include <cstddef>  // for size_t
#include <cstdio>   // for printf
#include <cwchar>   // for wmemcpy, wcslen

int main() {
  auto const str = L"Abcdefghijk";

  auto const sz = std::wcslen(str);
  auto const split_count = sz / 4 + (sz % 4 != 0); // round up division

  using split_t = wchar_t[5];
  split_t* splits = new split_t[split_count];

  std::size_t i = 0;
  for (; i + 1 < split_count; ++i) {
    std::wmemcpy(splits[i], str + i * 4, 4);
    splits[i][4] = 0;
  }
  std::wmemcpy(splits[i], str + i * 4, sz - i * 4 + 1);  // copies \0 too

  for (i = 0; i < split_count; ++i)
    std::printf("%ls\n", splits[i]);

  delete[] splits;
}
```